# No sound on Rakarrack 6.0.1

Tags: 12.04, sound, jack

I just installed [Rakarrack](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rakarrack/) and get no audio. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Help is appreciated.

Comment: more info is required

Answer (score 1):

Like many professional audio tools [Rakarrack](http://rakarrack.sourceforge.net/) needs Jack audio server. In order to get audio outputs working you may have to configure Jack (see the [Jack Wiki](http://trac.jackaudio.org/) for details).

This configuration depends very much on your individual set up. A generally valid answer can therefore hardly be given. One thing you may want to set up however is [pulseaudio integration](http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/PulseOnJack) for applications that don't work with Jack (but [read also this](http://jackaudio.org/pulseaudio_and_jack)).